# Number of Computing units in OpenCL

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

```
_kernel void kmp(__global char pattern[2*4], __global char* string, __global int failure[2*4], __global int ret[2], int g_length, int l_length, int thread_num){
    int pattern_num = 2;
    int pattern_size = 4;
    int gid = get_group_id(0);
    int glid = get_global_id(0);
    int lid = get_local_id(0);
    int i, j, x = 0;
    int old = 0;

    __local char tmp_string[32768];
    event_t event;

    event  = async_work_group_copy(tmp_string+lid*l_length, string+glid*l_length, l_length, 0);
    wait_group_events(1, &event);

    for(i = 0; i < pattern_num; i++){
            x = i*pattern_size;
            for(j = lid*l_length; j < (lid+1)*l_length; j++){
                    while(tmp_string[j] != pattern[x] && x > 0 && x != i*pattern_size){
                            x = failure[x-1]+i*pattern_size;
                    }

                    if(tmp_string[j] == pattern[x]){
                            if(x == (i+1)*pattern_size-1){
                                    //ret[i]++;
                                    old = atomic_add(&ret[i], 1);
                                    x = failure[x]+i*pattern_size;
                            }

                            else{
                                    x++;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
}
```

I need help with this code.

To find the matched pattern in the string, I wrote code like this.

I'm using AMD Hawaii and it has 44 groups which have 64 cores in each group(Total 2816 computing units, I mean).

The problem is when I try using more than 44 computing units(Using more than 1 core in one group; like 88 units-using 2 cores in each group- or 2816 units-using 64 cores in each group-), it doesn't work well.

It couldn't correctly find the matched number.

I checked the index of string, ids(glid, gid, lid) and the size of all variable.

But, there is nothing wrong.

Anyone who has some advice, please help!

Answer (score 0):

What is going wrong that you saying it doesn't work well? Also why are you not doing anything within async copy? Maybe a simple global to local assignment could work. Why is there a local barrier at the end of kernel?

Anyway, the error seems to be the async copy. It has different values for each thread in a group. For it to work right, it must be given exact same numbers in all threads of a group. Thats why it works with local size = 1 and not for bigger local groups.

For example, `glid` is different for all 64 threads in a group so it wouldn't work. Async work group copy command makes all threads of a group work on same copy. Not different copies. If you need different copies, you need multiple async commands serially but they would work async if you use the waiting on all of them at once.

Comment: Not working well means it cannot find the exact answer(I expected it to find 443 matched number, for example, it just find 230 or less). And I think I have to use barrier at the end of using local memory so use barrier at there. 
Anyway, if it has 88 threads, isn't it has the same numbers in all threads group? Do you mean all threads copy the same amount of size for the same index? 
Then can I use 
event  = async_work_group_copy(tmp_string+lid*l_length, string+glid*l_length, l_length, 0);
event  = async_work_group_copy(tmp_string+(lid+1)*l_length, string+glid*l_length, l_length, 0); ?

Comment: async copy command is like another kernel with a range and a start point and all threads work on it implicity. All threads have to run exact same parameters for it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But.. I still don't understand how to use it exactly. I changed my code like this;         
for(i = 0 ; i < glid; i++){
event  = async_work_group_copy(tmp_string+glid*l_length, string+glid*l_length, l_length, 0);
wait_group_events(1, &event); }.
It doesn't work well anyway. What do I misunderstand?

Comment: all threads must see same command with same parameters. dont use global id  nor local id. you can use only base pointer and group id and some other variables that is same for each thread. doesn't matter if it is in a loop. You can loop it but it will be serial then. if you need strided copy, there is a strided version of this